# MongoDB aggregation and paging

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have documents with my internal id field inside of each document and date when this document was added. There could be number of documents with the same id (differents versions of the same document), but dates will always be different for those documents. I want in some query, to bring only one document from all versions of the same document (with same id field) that was relevant to specified date, and I want to display them with paging (50 rows in the page). So, is there any chance to do this in MongoDB (operations - query documents by some field, group them by id field, sort by date field and take only first, and all this should be with paging.) ?

Please see example :Those are documents, some of them different documents,like documents A,B and C, and some are versions of the same documents,
like _id: 1, 2 and 3 are all version of the same document A

Document A {
_id : 1,
"id" : "A",
"author" : "value",
"date" : "2015-11-05"
}

Document A {
_id : 2,
"id" : "A",
"author" : "value",
"date" : "2015-11-06"
}

Document A {
_id : 3,
"id" : "A",
"author" : "value",
"date" : "2015-11-07"
}

Document B {
_id : 4,
"id" : "B",
"author" : "value",
"date" : "2015-11-06"
}

Document B {
_id : 5,
"id" : "B",
"author" : "value",
"date" : "2015-11-07"
}

Document C {
_id : 6,
"id" : "C",
"author" : "value",
"date" : "2015-11-07"
}

And I want to query all documents that has "value" in the "author" field. 
And from those documents to bring only one document of each with latest date for
 the specified date, for example 2015-11-08. So, I expect the result to be :
 _id : 3, _id : 5, _id : 6
 And also paging , for example 10 documents in each page.

Thanks !!!!!

Comment: What do you have that you can query with? The id? The date? A range of dates? Do you only want to get the latest id? What query have you created so far that is not working?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, please see updated question with example. In general I want to bring all documents that has "value" in some field, and from each different document I want to bring only latest version (specified by date field) to the specified date (example 2015-11-08). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Two documents can't have the same `_id`. There is a unique index on `_id` by default.
2. As per 1. you need to have a compound `_id` field which includes the date:

```
    {
      "_id":{
        docId: yourFormerIdValue,
        date: new ISODate()
      }
      // other fields
    }
```

3. To get the version valid at a specified date, the query becomes rather easy:

   ```
   db.yourColl.find({ 
     "_id":{
       "docId": idToFind,
       // get only the version valid up to a specific date...
       "date":{ "$lte": someISODate }
     }
   })
   // ...sort the results descending...
   .sort("_id.date":-1)
   // ...and get only the first and therefor newest entry
   .limit(1)
   ```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, the _id is different of course for each document, but, let say "my_id" - field in each document that is my id, is the same. Thanks for your reply, can you please advise how can I do paging in such query ? Thanks again !!!!